# LockService - Cell is still being overwritten

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have set up a spreadsheet bounded script as web app which processes get requests. I want to prevent the spreadsheet from overwriting rows, which is why I'm using the LockService to prevent this. I'm using the getScriptLock() method for this.

The problem is that when the web app is receiving concurrent requests the LockService seems to fail. I have set up my minimal reproducible example like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  const randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  const success = lock.tryLock(10000);

  if (success) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(randomNumber);
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  lock.releaseLock();

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done");
}
```

I started with a blank spreadsheet. It should store a random number for each request in a new row in the first column. To make sure it handles multiple requests at the same time well, I set up a spreadsheet with the web app url 20 times, appended by a parameter with an increasing value. You can open those urls at the same time by selecting them all and pressing left alt + enter on your keyboard. Now the concurrent requests are made.

The problem I have is that the cells are being overwritten. I have created a video to show the behaviour: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9BiktDnhic

What am I doing wrong? For some reason running `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` one line above the `getScriptLock()` call seems to solve the issue. But... why?

[The list of urls with an increasing parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojtCx.png)

Comment: This may be a bug related to the [v8 runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) as I cannot reproduce it when using the old Rhino interpreter. If all you need to do is append a row, try using the [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) method, which should work without a lock.

Comment: If you think this is a bug you can file this issue at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be a bug in Google Apps Scripts. The bug has been fixed. The issue can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193051316.

Answer (score 2):

The lock service doesn't prevent the cell from being overwritten it simply prevents simultaneous users from running the script at the same time.